# What String Replacement Java API's (Templating Library) are available to do conditional and custom string replacment?

Tags: java, substitution

I'm looking for an open-source Java API that allows me to do configurable string replacement based on custom tags.

#### Example Template:

```
Your did something<ACTION_DATETIME '" at "HH:mm AM" on "MM/dd/yyyy'> in[ {CITY}, {STATE}][ {ZIP5}]. Your's truly, [ {FIRST_INITIAL}][ {LAST_NAME}].
```

`<ACTION_DATETIME '" at "MM/dd/yyyy" on "HH:mm AM'>` tells us what date to use and the format of said date.

`[ {CITY}, {STATE}]` tells us to put the city and state here and if either field is null, to exclude everything between square brackets

#### Example Results:

```
Your did something at 1:32 PM on 10/13/2017 on in Mansfield, OH 44906. Your's truly, J Tully.
```

I've already got a solution partially built using regular expressions and regular string replacement, however I'm hoping for a more powerful and pre-built solution.

I've looked at Commons Lang3's StrSubstitutor, and while it handles simple and custom replacements, it doesn't seem to have the more syntax driven replacements.

#### Update#1

Currently stuck on Java 1.6.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a templating library at this point. Have you tried Thymeleaf?

Comment: Java 9 has a [Matcher.replaceAll](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) where you can submit a function

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a Templating Library.
Unfortunately, upgrading to Java 9 is not an option at this time. We're currently stuck on Java6 until the client approves us upgrading.

Comment: Looking into Thymeleaf and Freemarker as suggested to see if they do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy's suggestion of a templating library is the best option. There are many, I use [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) a bit.

Basically you have a template:

```
You did ${action} at ${date} in ${city} ${state} ${zip}. Yours truly, ${firstName} ${lastName}.
```

And a model (a java class) that contains the data:

```
class MyTemplate extends StringTemplate {

    public MyTemplate(String action, Date date, /* etc */ ) { /* set the model state */ }

    public String getTemplateFileLocation() { /* point to the template file */ }

    public String process() { /* process the template and return the string */ }

    public String getAction() { /* return the action as a string */ }

    public String getDate() { /* return the formatted date as a string, i.e. */ 
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        return df.format(date);
    }

    public String getCity() { /* return the city as a string */ }

    public String getState() { /* return the state as a string */ }

    public String getZip() { /* return the zip code as a string */ }

    public String getFirstName() { /* return the first name as a string */ }

    public String getLastName() { /* return the last name as a string */ }
}
```

Then in your code you can instantiate the template and process it. Processing the template replaces instances of `${firstName}` in the template with the return value of `getFirstName()` in the model (and so on, for each variable):

```
StringTemplate template = new MyTemplate(action, date, city, state, zip, firstName, lastName);
String letter = template.process();
```

Now `letter` contains the template populated with the values from the model.

There's a lot of different templating libraries, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Does it allow for stripping out subsets of text if the value is null?
Example: For something like `[in {CITY}, {STATE}]` if either value is null I'd like to prevent everything between the square brackets (or an equivalent) to be removed. Note: The "in " and ", " need to be configurable in the database on a per template basis.

Comment: Sure, you can do all of that stuff in the model - it's just Java, transform the text how you like, the template itself should be quite simple.